# Matching Image to word with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

newbie to typescript here. I'm trying to have an array of emotions and an array of images (faces) that the person has to match. So far I've tried using in memory database services but no luck and been struggling for a while. Any suggestions help would be much appreciated.

**in-memory-data.service.ts**

```
import {
InMemoryDbService
} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
      const emotions = [{
     { id: 11, name: 'HAPPY1', path: 'clip.jpg' },
     { id: 12, name: 'HAPPY2', path: '../../assets/mood.jpg' },
     { id: 13, name: 'HAPPY3', path: '../../assets/mood.jpg' },
     { id: 14, name: 'HAPPY4', path: '../../assets/mood.jpg' },
     { id: 15, name: 'HAPPY5', path: '../../assets/mood.jpg' },
    ];


   const faces= [
  { id: 11, name: 'HAPPY' },
  { id: 12, name: 'SAD' },
  { id: 13, name: 'ANGRY' },
  { id: 14, name: 'EXCITED' },
  { id: 15, name: 'ANXIOUS' },


];

return {faces, emotions};
}
   }
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Emotion } from 'emotion';
import { EmotionService } from 'emotion.service';
import { FaceService } from 'face.service';
import { Face } from 'face';


@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  emotions: Emotion[] = [];
  faces: Face[] = [];

  constructor(private emotionService: EmotionService, private faceService: FaceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmotions();
    this.getFaces();

    /*
 imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = '../../assets/mood.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = '../../assets/mood.jpg';

/* ... more images ... 

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = '../../assets/mood.jpg'; */
}
    //if clicked, game starts
    show: boolean = true;


    //using these methods just to check if button click is sending somewhere( opens alert box)
    submitFace(event, f: string){
    console.log(f);
    alert('Open: ' + f);
    }

    submitEmotion(event, e: string,  f: string){
    //console.log("Random number: " Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + "emotion: " + e);//would like that only 1 random face appeared each time
    alert('Open: ' + e + f);
   //if (emotion == face ){
    //alert('win: ' + e);
    // if (emotion != face ){
    //alert('win: ' + face);
   // }
   // }
    }


   //  this.emotions =  this.emotionService.getEmotions().filter(x => x.id == this.emotionId)[0];


  //getMAtch(): void{
  //var matches_array = this.emotionService.getEmotions().match(this.faces)
  //console.log(matches_array);




  //will be images, want one to appear in each itteration 
  getFaces(): void {

    this.faceService.getFaces().subscribe(faces => this.faces = faces.slice(0, 1));

  }
    //want all to appear in each itteration
  getEmotions(): void {

    this.emotionService.getEmotions().subscribe(emotions => this.emotions = emotions.slice(0, 2));
  }

  /*
 nextImage(element: string){
   img = document.getElementById(element);

    for( i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src) // << check this
        {
            if(i === imgArray.length){
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}
*/

} //end bracket
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="grid grid-pad">

  <a *ngFor="let face of faces" class="col-1-3" (click)="submitEmotion($event, face.name)" routerLink="/detail/{{face.id}}" img [attr.src]="face.path">
    <div class="module face">
    <h4>{{face.path}}</h4>
    </div>
   </a>

<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let emotion of emotions" class="col-1-3"  (click)="submitEmotion($event, emotion.name)" routerLink="/detail/{{emotion.id}}">
    <div class="module emotion">

    <h4>{{emotion.name}}</h4>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

<emotion-search></emotion-search>
<face-search></face-search>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on the exact error you're getting?  Is it a typescript error, a javascript syntax error, an angular error...or is it just not working as expected?

Comment: Well the images in the face data service don't come through for starters. But overall, I'm struggling with the general way to go about this, as you can see in the dashboard component I tried a few different methods but none worked.

Comment: There's a lot going on in this example, including importing a lot of your own code that isn't included here. It might be helpful to pare down the example to focus on the parts where you're having trouble. Is it the communication between the in-memory data service and the faces/emotions services? Or between the faces/emotions services and the dashboard component? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Angular, so I'm not sure if there is something specific you are doing that is causing issues.

However, being really meticulous about breaking your program into smaller and smaller pieces, and using `console.log` to see if it's functioning as you expect could help:

For example in your getFaces method:

```
getFaces(): void {

  this.faceService.getFaces().subscribe(faces => this.faces = faces.slice(0, 1));
```

...try logging out each peice.

```
}

getFaces(): void {
  console.log('in getFaces method');

  this.faceService.getFaces().subscribe(faces => {
    console.log(' - subscribing')
    console.log(' - faces', faces);

    const slice = faces.slice(0, 1);

    consolt.log(' - slice', slice);

    this.faces = slice;
  });
}
```

Does faces exist?  Is the first element what you expect?  For example do you really want an array (`faces.slice(0, 1);`), or the first face in the array (`faces[0]`)?

Repeat this process for each component.